# how can I setURL friendly urls in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I set SEO friendl urls like http://bodyharmonynutrition.com/eating-a-heart-healthy-diet/ in my site ?

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, for more granular control consider using the all in one seo plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/

Answer (score 1):

Enable [Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) in Wordpress

There's 4 options for you to choose to cater for your needs.

[image]